# SQLite structure advice

Tags: sql, sqlite, database-design

I have a book structure with Chapter, Subchapter, Section, Subsection, Article and unknown number of subarticles, sub-subarticles, sub-sub-subarticles etc.

What's the best way to structure this?
One table with child-parent relationships, multiple tables?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of methods to save a tree structure in a relational database. The most commonly used are using parent pointers and [nested sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model).

The first has a very easy data structure, namely a pointer to the respective parent element on each object), and is thus easy to implement. On the downside it is not easy to make some queries on it as the tree can not be fully traversed. You would need a self-join per layer.

The nested set is easier to query (when you have understood how it works) but is harder to update. Many writes require additional updates to other objects ion the tree which might make it harder to be transitionally save.

A third variant is that of the [materialized path](https://communities.bmc.com/communities/docs/DOC-9902) which I personally consider a good compromise between the former two.

That said, if you want to store arbitrary size trees (e.g,. for sections, sub-sections, sub-sub-sections, ...) you should use one of the mentioned tree implementations. If you have a very limited maximum depth (e.g max 3 layers) you could get away with creating an explicit data structure. But as things always get more complex than initially though, I'd advise you to use a real tree implementation.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at the links later on. I do need to traverse the tree with queries.

Answer (score 4):

To determine whether there are seperate tables or one-big-table involved, you should take a close look at each item - chapter, subchapter, etc. - and decide if they carry different attributes from the others. Does a chapter carry something different from a sub-chapter?

If so, then you're looking at seperate tables for Chapter, SubChapter, Section, SubSection, Article. Article still feels hierarchical to me with your sub- sub-sub- sub-sub-sub- etc.

If not, then maybe it is one big table with parent/child, but it looks like you may be talking about 'names' for the depth of the hierarchy which leans me toward seperate tables again.

Also consider how you'll query and what you'll be searching for.

Comment: If the data is the same except, perhaps, for some sort of "level identifier", then make it one recursive table. If there's different data -- if, say, chapters have individual authors but lower levels don't, and articles have footnotes but higher levels don't, etc -- then you need different tables. I wouldn't be too dogmatic, like if there's one extra column at one level and you can harmlessly make it null for other levels, fine, keep it in one table. But if there are lots of differences, then they really are different entities.

Comment: Thanks, my only problem with making one big table is if I have something like Parent->child 1->child 2->child 3, how do I select Parent of child 3 for example. I need to do this with queries.